# Can I use Ubuntu One on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ubuntu-one, raspberrypi

I am an Ubuntu One user on multiple platforms and want to know if there is a way I can use Ubuntu One with my Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stuart Langridge from the Ubuntu One team has a post up from 2012 entitled "Accessing Ubuntu One file storage via FTP from any OS" which contains YouTube videos and links to the U1FTP code that would let you do so from Raspbian or any other operating system on an RPi.  The discussion is available here: http://kryogenix.org/days/2012/09/11/accessing-ubuntu-one-file-storage-via-ftp-from-any-os

Comment: Thanks! It was very easy to setup and use.  Now I can move code between my Pi and my many computers from anywhere.